# Post function not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Please check the jquery post function below. For some reason, it isn't posting data to specific URL. Is this code correct?

What wrong am I doing here any idea?

```
$.post("/Administrator/ProductEditProcess", { id: _id, title: _title, CategoryId: _CategoryId, slug: _slug, description: _description, isGuest: _isGuest, isActive: _isActive, isExclusiveSold: _isExclusiveSold, isFeatured: _isFeatured }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log("trigred");
                    if (data == "ok") {
                        alert("Success");
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: what error are you getting ? server side/client side ? we need more information

Comment: The server side url not getting any call from this code above. And yes no error showing even console.log("trigred"); not displays

Comment: so maybe this portion of code it not running? did you include all the necessary ? what are you getting in the console ?

Comment: Yes jquery added. no problem at all.

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, go to the network tab, and see if anything is being posted or not. If it is being posted, the issue might be obvious when observing it in this way

Comment: Please add a `.fail()` call along with your `.done()` to actually see the errors raised by the server: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR / https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering you have no errors/warnings in your console - there could be not so many reasons it does not work - e.g., your action address`/Administrator/ProductEditProcess` either does not exist or has errors in its code - check that twice.

Also, `$.post` (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/, which is short form of https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) has extremely useful methods `.done(function(response){})` and `.fail(function(response){})` methods, which provide you with a response data allowing you to debug much easier.

Comment: yeah i am having issue with input parameters which posting to route

Comment: What was the actual solution? please don't accept this as an answer... it isn't an answer.

Comment: `it isn't posting data to specific URL. What wrong am I doing here any idea?` -> `action address/Administrator/ProductEditProcess either does not exist or has errors in its code` - don't these two match one another? Also, considering presence of only tag `jquery` and absence of any other. Please, do not throw bare objection w/o any arguments - either explain why is it so, why you object/appeal, or, better, propose actual solution of yours. Otherwise, you do not differ much from what you are complaining of.